# Connecting to Google Cloud Storage using service account in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I am writing a simple Java program to upload text files to a cloud storage bucket in my project. I tried the simple example given in the google documentation, in which it uses default instances of a project to connect to it.
Here is the code:

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket;  
import com.google.cloud.storage.BucketInfo;  
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;  
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;  

public class QuickstartSample {
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
// Instantiates a client
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();`  

// The name for the new bucket
String bucketName = "shapy-bucket-v3";

// Creates the new bucket
Bucket bucket = storage.create(BucketInfo.of(bucketName));

System.out.printf("Bucket %s created.%n", bucket.getName());
 }
}
```

Now I want to use a google service account to connect to my storage.I have made the service account using p12 format with admin rights. I have the .p12 file but I don't know how to connect my Java program to my storage using the service account.

Comment: Show us your efforts

Comment: @sForSujit I have added my code. If you have a solution pls share it.